# Related to trigonometric problem

Tags: trigonometry

I was studying some problem related to trigonometry from a book and it states that:

Let $m$ be an integer such that $2m<x<2m+1$

$\implies 2m\pi<\pi x< (2m+1)\pi$

$\implies 0<sin \pi x<1$.

Similarly, for $2m-1<x<2m$, we have $-1<sin\pi x<0$.

How they derived this identity when we know that $sin$ always take $0$ value on integral product of $\pi$. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that between an **even** multiple and an **odd** multiple of $\pi$ (with $2m\pi<(2m+1)\pi$), there is a multiple of ${\pi\over2}$ so $0<\sin\pi x \le1$. It is analogous for the other case, but with multiples of ${3\over2}\pi$ (between an **odd** multiple and an **even** multiple of $\pi$, with $(2m-1)\pi<2m\pi$) where the sine is $-1$.